# How to write a memory stream into a tif file?

Tags: c#, tiff, multipage

I have a multi-page tiff created on `TiffBitmapEncoder te= new TiffBitmapEncoder()`; (using CCITT4)

Then I copy this to a memory stream 
    Say `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()` using `ts.save(ms);`

Now this memory stream has a tiff image of many pages. I just need to write it to to tiff file. I don't want to write it again through Bitmap.Save(location,coded,parameters) as using `(long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4` produces error on 2003 windows machines.

I tried resetting ms to position 0 and writing to a Image and save to an imagelocation. But this writes only 1 page tiff.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just write directly to a `FileStream`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders You should post that as an answer

Comment: I suspect this statement "memory stream has a tiff image of many pages" is already false as it is unlikely any code that copies MemoryStream to a file to change data in the stream. (Also showing your call to `CopyTo` to copy memory stream to file would confirm that).

Comment: @OndrejTucny yeah,I was playing with Image and Bitmap to files so far as I was using the same way to write Images so far. I have been dealing with lots of other issues wrt to this and lost in the last step

Comment: @John Just now tried it to filestream before coming here. And found answer here too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The problem is with windows 2003 server where CompressionCCITT4  produces error. So had to come up with a work around to create 1bpp image. I cannot use saveadd() of bitmap.

Comment: One more time - how did you verified your statement "memory stream has a tiff image of many pages"? I'm almost  certain that it does not contain "image of many pages". Please, show your code at least for copying stream to file (The one behind "resetting ms to position 0 and writing to a Image and save to an imagelocation")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes,I was using a modified version of http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-HK/netfxbcl/thread/1585c562-f7a9-4cfd-9674-6855ffaa8653

Comment: As a work around for "Parameter is not valid" for CompressionCCITT4 on Windows Server 2003 and 2008" issue

Comment: Used Image.FromStream(memorystream). And I never really worked with any of these methods if these were not supposed to be used that way. I was just trying it out !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply write directly to a `FileStream`. There is no need to use a `MemoryStream` first.